# ArrayAdapter throws a NullPointer error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to add a navigation drawer and I'm using the same google code sample.

But i get a null error at ArrayAdapter.

```
public class HomeActivity extends AbstractBaseActivity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private String[] mSettiltles;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    mSettiltles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_items);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    //  mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mSettiltles));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
    }
}
```

I've set my String array in my string values.

```
 <string-array name="menu_items">
    <item>My Schedule</item>
    <item>TripSummary</item>
    <item>Feedback</item>
</string-array>
```

Please help.

Thank you.

Logcat

```
12-18 06:33:41.690    1486-1486/com.myntra.delivery E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myntra.delivery/com.myntra.delivery.activities.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.myntra.delivery.activities.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:49)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
```

at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Comment: Whats the purpose of `mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();` ???

Comment: Why are you inflating layout two time in your `onCreate` method ?

Comment: what does `getTitle()` contains ?

Comment: U can ignore gettitle for now. The error is in the ArrayAdapter. GrlsHu- That was copy paste error.

Comment: Now your `mSettiltles` is null.

Comment: No I'm setting an array from strings resource file.

Comment: Does you `activity_home` layout contain a view with id `left_drawer`?

Comment: I had misplaced the layout. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose line #49 is this one:

```
mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mSettiltles));
```

Therefore, NPE can only origin from `mDrawerList` being `null`.
So obviously, your layout does not contain a View with id `left_drawer`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it's the line:

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);`

And you probably put your ListView in another layout like `DrawerLayout` as implied by the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).  Try changing the `setContentView` to point to the layout where the ListView can be found.